# why var clientPeople = <%- JSON.stringify(serverPeople) %>; console.log(typeof clientPeople); returns as object not string inside of ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

This code is running inside of an ejs file:

Questions is why

```
var clientPeople = <%- JSON.stringify(serverPeople) %>;
console.log(typeof clientPeople); 

//returns as an object not a string
```

Comment: Because it's an object with JSON key/values. `stringify` doesn't wrap the entire output in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientPeople = '<%- JSON.stringify(serverPeople) %>';
console.log(typeof clientPeople);
```

This should return string

Comment: Hi Seyi, I don't need it to be string, I just want to understand why JSON.stringify(serverPeople) is not converting to string   Thank you for your response

Comment: Because it's an object with JSON key/values. and stringify from EJS will  return JavaScript object literals, which you'll be passing into a variable to be processed on the client i.e. Browser. So this will result in `var clientPeople = {"y": "this is what we get from the stringify" };`. And this will be regarded as JS object literals on the browser after getting this from the server. I hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you Seyi, let me know if my understanding is correct.  <%- JSON.stringify(object) %> will return an javascript object literal? So it is the behavior from ejs then?

Comment: @Hui, yes kinda, it's because of the environment, it's a server language, that can dynamically create stuff for the client/browser to process.